When "You are in an image" using Voiceover, - how to find out what the image is?
I am using voiceover to navigate a page and right off the bat I get the message "You are in an image" I don't really know what image it is. Is there a way to find out, for example if I could do CMD-C to copy the image that would be great, but doesn't seem to work.
What are the various ways one can use to find that actual image that Voiceover tells me I am on.

Does this article help?
